# Enum for error codes from a 3rd party API?

Tags: java, api, enums

I'm using an API which returning error codes in string format. I was wondering if I can organize the codes into an enum.

But new codes may be added. And it is highly possible because the API is kinda young. Then I need to change and recompile my code. Using String type is still an option. But I'd like to use an enum if I can.

What's the best practice to deal with error codes?

Comment: Using strings wouldn't prevent recompilation if you're referencing them explicitly. It would introduce some fragility though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirement. 
String could be good you dont need to change again and again.
But enum is easier to use.
Another way could be, if you know in advance, how the errorcode may be classified, then you may do a mapping between the original errorcode and the internal error code you use, then you can create enum for those internal error code, those internal error code could be more stable. Hope to answer your concerns.